# How do I set a root password for a Cloud SQL instance in Google App Engine? ["Instance busy" error message]

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, root, google-cloud-sql

Whenever I try to set a root password I get a message saying "Instance busy".

How can I then set a password for the instance? Is there a third party tool I can use to connect to the cloud-sql instance and maybe set a password from there?

Comment: What do you see on the operations log? Normally you'd see the "instance busy" message for a couple of seconds and then you should be able to connect with your new password.

Comment: Hi - thanks for commenting. It just keeps saying "Instance busy".

It disables the input field for a short while, then goes back, then says "Instance busy" again.

The password cannot be set.

Comment: how are you setting the password? with `$ gcloud sql instances set-root-password your-instance-name --password password´ ? or with some special commands?

Comment: Via the instance-options through the console.

I am not using a terminal.

Comment: Just a hunch: maybe try restarting the instance? https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/instances#restarting

Comment: I have tried that, same error applies just after restarting.

Comment: Does your user account have sufficient permissions to set passwords?

Comment: yes, my permission can't be any higher.

Answer (score 1):

I have found no resolve, and the issue persists.

However, if you remove the IP address to the instance periodically, there should be no way of accessing it outside the internal app engines code.

This bug is still a big security concern though.

Answer (score 1):

Using the new console, try waiting for a good length of time if you haven't already, as that message eventually went away for me

Once I set the password I just used MySQL Workbench to connect, and it was all copacetic.

---

**Background:**
I just set up my Cloud SQL this week, and in the [Developers Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) under Access Control and I had the same problem at first, in the small yellow box "Instance Busy".

My solution was to clear my cache on Chrome (I recommend using Chrome with Google UIs as it rules out any funky incompatibility with AngularJS), I saw the error message again after I went back, waited a while (maybe 30 seconds) and it went away, I then assigned an IP address and it came back, again for a while and eventually went away and I was able to set the password then.

Hopefully this answer was helpful (and it works for you; although not guaranteed I thought I would offer it as an answer as my experience was very similar).